# Javascript executing despite ruby conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements

I'm having a small issue with javascript code being executed with no regards for ruby conditional statements.

Despite both pieces of JS being executed, only the right HTML balises are shown. (if notice, I'll only see `<div role="notice">` and if it's the error, I'll only see `<div role="alert">` but the javascript inside is definitely executed no matter what)

```
- if notice
  .row
    %div{role: 'notice'}
      :javascript
        toastr.success('#{notice}','Success')
      })
- if alert
  .row
    %div{role: 'alert'}
      :javascript
      $(function () {
        toastr.error('#{alert}','Error')
      })
```

I must be missing something obvious, but I can't seem to find what it is.

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Doesn't seem like an issue with the JS, its with your local vars for alert and notice.  Add a Rails.logger.info statement inside each of your if statements, e.g. 'Rails.logger.info("Inside alert: #{alert}")`, and you'll see that it's hitting in both places.

Comment: Check what is happening with `= notice` and `= alert` statements (print out values in haml). replace `notice` and `alert` with false to check whether you are at home.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion guys.
The other variable is indeed empty, but the problem got somehow corrected when I removed $(function () { around the JS call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I've corrected some indents.

```
- if notice
  .row
    %div{role: 'notice'}
      :javascript
        $(function () {
          toastr.success('#{notice}','Success')
        })

- if alert
  .row
    %div{role: 'alert'}
      :javascript
        $(function () {
          toastr.error('#{alert}','Error')
        })
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply
Your formatting works, I just needed to remove $(function () { and }) around the call.
Thanks again